# how to pull only git logs without pulling the whole file tree and diffs

Tags: git, clone

I have a server that has limited storage space and I need to track a git repository, but I am only interested in the log messages and not the whole repository (blobs, diffs, tags, ...). the repository that I'm willing to track has a large commit history, and above that it stores some large binary files which makes it impossible to sync and pull everything.

now I'm wondering if there a way to pull only git logs from a branch!

and if possible is possible to pull logs after or before a commit hash?

Comment: I need to get all logs, I guess the answer you refer to is only interested in cloning a repository with only recent changes

Comment: The accepted answer is strangely worded in that it doesn't answer the question, but provides a solution for the desired goal as described later in the question. The second answer is worded better. Basically, the answer is no, you can't.

Comment: `git clone --bare --filter=blob:none`

Comment: @phd The two times I tried `--filter=blob:none` the results of my clone were pretty much identical to without that filter...

Comment: @TTT Very much depends how well the server supports protocol v2. Anyway this is the only way to fetch commits but not fetch files.